# What is OOB in OAuth?

Tags: oauth

I'm only starting to explore what OAuth and I have barely any clue of the related terms.
In a PHP code snippet, I saw :

```
// Callback can either be 'oob' or a url

$callback='oob';
```

I'd like to know what oob is?

Comment: My guess is "Out-Of-Band". Meaning the token will be transferred using a method outside of the scope of OAuth.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*oob* usually stands for "out of band".  I would assume that this is to support OAuth responses that come through an unspecified method.

Answer (score 8):

OOB ("out of band") is an alternative to the traditional 3-step process of an OAuth flow (known as 3-Legged-OAuth). The user is not redirected after granting access to a consumer, instead, a code is shown to the user which he needs to manually input in the Consumer App. The difference is outlined in the **step 2b** below.

**An OAuth1a flow**:

Step 1: Get a short lived `request_token` which can be used to access the User Authorization URL.

Step 2: Use the `request_token` to access and show the User Authorization URL to the user. The user will see a screen where he can accept or decline access; the tipical "Do you want to give App ABC access on your behalf?".

Step 2a (callback url): If a `callback_url` has been provided, the user will be redirected to that callback URL. The URL will include the parameter `oauth_verifier` which contains a code, needed for step 3.

**Step 2b (callback is `oob`)**: If the `callback_url` is set to `oob`, the user will not be redirected. Instead, the `oauth_verifier` code is shown to the user. This must be implemented by the Provider. The user can use this code in the Consumer App, usually a mobile app or any other non-browser based App, to continue to step 3.

Step 3: The `oauth_verifier` code (and Request Token) is used to get a long-lived `access_token`. The Consumer can now make calls to the (REST)-API of the Provider using this token in his OAuth calls (the request still needs other OAuth parameters and needs to be signed etc.).

Further info:

[Pin based authorization with Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/pin-based-oauth)

[OAuth1a core specification - Request URLs](https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#request_urls)